# How deal with big gzipped dumps in PHP (without grep)?

Tags: php, windows, search, gzip

I have a big GZ file ("Turtle RDF" file) (about ~15Gb compressed, ~88 uncompressed), and I need to know if there is a solution with PHP to find the lines whoes contains specific string.

I found this [solution by zerkms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3010533/1536534) but my dev environment is **Windows**. I tested `gzopen`, `gzgets`, `gzread` but I cannot find how search in the file and keep some performances at the same time.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `zcat file.gz | grep 'whatever'`?

Comment: @MarcB Hi! Like i said, i don't think I can use grep. Because of my dev environment (Windows). I'm wrong?

Comment: @MarB or just `zgrep 'whatever' file.gz`

Comment: there's `find` for windows, if necessary. grepping 88gigs is still going to be slow no matter what you do, especially if you have to decompress the file each time.

Comment: @MarcB Can I do that without decompression?

Comment: no. you cannot search for a string WITHOUT decompressing the text first. `gzip('foo')` v.s. `gzip('barfoobaz')` will produce two completely different compressed strings, and the compression equvialent of `foo` will not be the same as the `foo` inside `barfoobaz`.