# How to look for certain data and then output result

Tags: php

I am using PHP to execute a command using exec() which works fine.

example:

`exec("openssl s_client -connect www.domain.com:443 -sslv2 > results.txt");`

My question is how can I then read the file "results.txt" and look for certain sentence.. For example if the following exists in the text file:

> no peer certificate available

Then return "no results found".

The reason for this is the results.txt may contain alot of data but **I don't** want to return it all using `$getresults = file_get_contents('results.txt');`

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13246597/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-in-php

Comment: Then what is it exactly that you want to do? That answer shows you how to read a file line by line, so once you find the text you want, you stop reading the rest of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[speed string search in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010354/speed-string-search-in-php)

```
exec('grep "no peer certificate available" results.txt -b', $result);
var_dump($result);
```

Does it do the job to go on the right way ?

Comment: actually, this will not work for me since i am using windows.. not linux.. grep is not a valid command. so ill need a solution that will read the results.txt file

Comment: @user3436467 Grep is available for Windows.

Comment: ok installed grep, ran the code and got this `array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(32) "24:no peer certificate available"
}`